# Having trouble installing SimpleAuth for GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authentication, oauth, openid

I have been working for a while, trying to install SimpleAuth on Google App Engine and I am running in to trouble.  First off in the bottom of the sample code they have this:

```
def _get_consumer_info_for(self, provider):
       """Should return a tuple (key, secret) for auth init requests.
       For OAuth 2.0 you should also return a scope, e.g.
       ('my app id', 'my app secret', 'email,user_about_me')

       The scope depends solely on the provider.
       See example/secrets.py.template
       """
       return secrets.AUTH_CONFIG[provider]
```

and I don't see the secrets file anywhere nor what it is supposed to do.

Then in addition to that small problem I am curious how I am supposed to render the providers and their login URLs to the user.  This page: https://github.com/crhym3/simpleauth/blob/master/example/handlers.py has a great description of the general setup but it doesn't have any description of what we actually need to pass to the user to let them login.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First off, please take into account that it's just an example, so some code parts were simplified for the demo purposes.

`secrets` is a separate module. The README file says to copy [secrets.py.template](https://github.com/crhym3/simpleauth/blob/master/example/secrets.py.template) into secrets.py and set proper client/consumer ids and secrets. Again, see README for info on where to get client/secrets for different providers.

The rendering is up to you. What I did as [an example](https://github.com/crhym3/simpleauth/blob/master/example/templates/home.html) is this:

```
<p>Try logging in with one of these:</p>
<a href="/auth/google">Google</a>
<a href="/auth/facebook">Facebook</a>
<a href="/auth/openid?identity_url=me.yahoo.com">Yahoo! (OpenID)</a>
<a href="/auth/twitter">Twitter</a>
<a href="/auth/linkedin">LinkedIn</a>
<a href="/auth/windows_live">Windows Live</a>
```

Those `/auth/...` links should get routed to your handler (normally webapp2.RequestHandler or some subclass) that's mixed in with `SimpleAuthHandler`.

You can see the example app live at https://simpleauth.appspot.com, hopefully it'll clarify things.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful post. That clears up one of my big questions but I had read the readme and I didn't see any file called secrets.py which led to some of the confusion. Is that a file that we should create on our own?

Comment: Yes. There's a template that you can start from, identical to what should be the secrets.py. It's example/secrets.py.template: https://github.com/crhym3/simpleauth/blob/master/example/secrets.py.template Just copy it into secrets.py (without ".template" ending) and modify it, i.e. set real client/secrets.